# regex optional characters

Tags: php, regex

The 3 strings (here are HTML codes, please don't say use HTML parsers, I have to use RegEx):

```
</div><img src="http://www.example.com/nano.png" alt="NANOTECH" />
</div><img src="http://www.example.com/internet.gif" alt="INTERNET" />
</div>
```

I want to capture there 3 lines. So tried this: (PHP `preg_match`)

```
<\/div>.[<img src="http:\/\/www.example.com\/.*?\/>]+
```

But it gets just `</div><img src="http://www.example.com/`

What's wrong?

Comment: I assume you're using PHP as you mention `preg_match`, what makes regex a requirement?

Comment: @zzzzBov: yes, I have to edit some files, and remove these strings. So I use `preg_` functions.

Comment: Why do you have to use regexes?  What places that constraint on you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need round brackets, not square ones. Square brackets denote a character class, which matches any single character of the ones in the brackets. You also don't want the dot between `/div>` and `<img`, since there's no gap between them in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Um, why don't you try

```
<\/div><img src="http:\/\/www.example.com\/.*?\/>
```

The reason why you are failing is that you use the square brackets `[]` to define a list of matching characters, and then tell the regex to match any of these characters once or more times (`+`). Since neither `i` nor `n` are included, the match stops at the beginning of `internet.gif` and `nano.png`, respectively.

Comment: because the `<img>` tag is optional. in the third string, I don't have any.

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with regex pattern

```
/^<\/div>(<img src="http:\/{2}www.example.com[^>]*>)?$/m
```

or use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with regex pattern

```
/(^<\/div>(<img src="http:\/{2}www.example.com[^>]*>)?$(?:\n?|\Z))+/m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(<\/div>(?:<img\w*src="http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/[^"]+?"[^>]*?>)?)/m
```

Also use preg_match_all to find not just one, but all matches.